# How to use output of grep for ping

Tags: scripts, grep, ping

I desperately try to use the output of grep for a script:

```
ping dc"$(grep -o .""\[12].domain.local"" /etc/squid3/squid.conf)"

ping "$(grep -o ""dc0\[12].domain.local"" /etc/squid3/squid.conf)"
```

Both return:

```
ping: unknown host dc02.domain.local
```

If I type in `ping dc02.domain.local`, it works! I can't see, what I'm doing wrong?

Relevant line of /etc/squid3/squid.conf is:

```
external_acl_type memberof %LOGIN /usr/lib/squid3/squid_ldap_group -R -K -b "dc=domain,dc=local" -D username@domain.local -W /aaa/bbb/ccc.txt -f "(&(objectclass=person)(sAMAccountName=%v)(memberof=cn=%g,ou=aaa,ou=bbb,ou=ccc,ou=ddd,ou=eee,dc=domain,dc=local))" -h dc02.domain.local
```

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer, but the suggested syntax results in: "ping: unknown host dc"

Comment: Please add the relevant content of the file `/etc/squid3/squid.conf` to your question..

Comment: Not in the comment, please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/674845/edit) your question and add this..

Comment: Please format it properly, as you can see it is all packed together..

Comment: Try `ping "$(grep -o '[^ ]\+$' /etc/squid3/squid.conf)"`

Comment: I changed the syntax to `ping "$(grep -o dc'[^ ]\+$' /etc/squid3/squid.conf)"` (because there are other lines) but it still returns `ping: unknown host dc02.domain.local`

Comment: Why have you changed the syntax? does the file differ from what you have posted ?

Comment: If it has more than one line that could be matched then this won't work..perhaps you should add the full content of the file..

Comment: just as i wrote above: the config file consists of several lines (would take lot of lines to post it here completely) and I only posted the relevant line (anonymisized). Your code extracted the last "word" of every line that resulted in one ping for the first line  (unsuccessful) and listings og the other "results"

Comment: Try `for i in $(grep -o '[^ ]\+$' /etc/squid3/squid.conf); do ping -c 4 "$i"; done`

Comment: hm, interesting. When he reaches the line containing the server, the ping runs correctly. (the other lines result in `ping: unknown host [whatever]` or `Invalid argument`, which is logical...) - but changing your syntax to `for i in $(grep -o dc'[^ ]\+$' /etc/squid3/squid.conf); do ping -c 4 "$i"; done` works! THANKS!!!

Comment: No problem, i have added an answer with explanation..please select it as accepted by clicking the tick mark on the left of the answer so that this issue can be marked as solved..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is failing is that the file `/etc/squid3/squid.conf` contains more that one line matching the pattern. So when you do

```
ping "$(grep ....)"
```

all the newline separated matches are being passed as a single argument to `ping` which takes only a single address at a time as argument hence it is failing.

Note that rather than using the Regex pattern you have used you can simplify the matching of the last word using :

```
grep -o 'dc[^ ]\+$' /etc/squid3/squid.conf
```

assuming the word starts with `dc`.

Finally as you have multiple addresses to run `ping` over, you should use a loop :

```
for i in $(grep -o 'dc[^ ]\+$' /etc/squid3/squid.conf); do ping -c 4 "$i"; done
```

`ping -c 4` will send 4 ICMP Echo_Request packets to each destination.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `awk`

```
awk -F'-h ' '/-h +dc0[12]/ {system("ping -c 3 "$2)}'
```

- `-F'-h '`

  We are interested in only what is behind `-h`.
- `/-h +dc0[12]\.domain\.local/`

  We are interested in only the string `dc01.domain.local` and `dc02.domain.local`

Comment: And much shorter!  ;-)